# How to connect my dialogflow to my google action and test it on a smart speaker

Tags: dialogflow-es

In the past I could connect dialogflow agent to a google actions project..... But It was just luck because now I can not do it again.
I follow this steps:
[https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/dialogflow/project-agent#:~:text=Create%20an%20Actions%20project%20and%20Dialogflow%20agent,-Go%20to%20the&text=Scroll%20down%20to%20the%20More,Custom%20intent%20card%2C%20click%20Build](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/dialogflow/project-agent#:%7E:text=Create%20an%20Actions%20project%20and%20Dialogflow%20agent,-Go%20to%20the&text=Scroll%20down%20to%20the%20More,Custom%20intent%20card%2C%20click%20Build).
Result is that I have a dialogflow agent that works fine but it seems the agent only works in the simulator build in and not in the test simulator in google actions or on my smart speaker.
How do I connect this agent to a google action. I look on the internet but never find a clear step-by-step guide!

Hope someone can help because this is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in DF console you can still use integrations, however I think it is better to start from Action Builder.

1. Visit: [Action Console](https://console.actions.google.com/)
2. If you already have a GCP project that has DF, it will appear in the list. If not you can create a new project.
3. Develop and test your bot
4. In order to test in your smart speaker you would need to deploy it

Once you create/choose a project in Actions Console you can see each step on console.